# ARM toolchain for ubuntu Error while compiling

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, embedded, arm

I am trying to make the ARM toolchain in ubuntu. The way it is specified in http://hri.sourceforge.net/tools/arm-elf-gcc.html

I am getting the following error:

```
Configuring for a x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu host.
Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized
Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized
Unrecognized host system name x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.
```

does anybody have idea whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Google-search on the "machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized" error message indicates that this can happen if the `config.guess` and `config.sub` files in the program you're building are too old to recognize the machine type for 64-bit linux.  I expect that's your problem.  You can fix that by replacing the ones in your GCC source tree with newer versions; your system should have some in the `/usr/share/libtool` directory that will work.  Alternately, compile in a 32-bit Linux installation, or with "--build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu" configure options.

There are also copies here:

[http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/config/config/config.guess](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/%2acheckout%2a/config/config/config.guess)

[http://savannah.gnu.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs/*checkout*/config/config/config.sub](http://savannah.gnu.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs/%2acheckout%2a/config/config/config.sub)

The real question, though, is: Why you are trying to build a version of the ARM toolchain that's that old?  The directions on the site you link to will lead you to download the sources for the 2.95.3 version of GCC -- which was released nearly a decade ago.  In GCC terms, that's positively ancient; the latest version is 4.5.  It's older than a lot of ARM instruction-set changes, too.

Thus, the right solution to your problem, unless you have some specific need for a 2.95 compiler, is to get a version of GCC that's much more recent.

Also, you'll probably save some pain by not compiling it yourself, unless you particularly want to.  There are numerous sources of precompiled cross-compilers; since I work at CodeSourcery, I'll recommend ours (which you can download and use for free):
  http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/subscription?@template=lite.  If you want something equivalent to the compiler on the page you linked to, you probably want the "uClinux" version.

Comment: Hi Brooks, thanks for the detailed explanation.  Unfortunately i am using a decade old board S3C44B0 processor (ARM 7). The uclinux distribution given with the board need old toolchain. Now i  feel the pain of having such a old board.

Comment: Ouch, yes!  In any case, hopefully one of the alternate suggestions I provided (replacing `config.*` or compiling a 32-bit version) will work for you.